# How do I bind my LINQ query results (put into a dictionary) to a Chart in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, dictionary, charts

Ok so I am just practicing what is probably some very basic stuff with charts in wpf. I am fairly new to linq and wpf, so I apologize in advance if this is a silly question. I've got my LINQ to entity query returning all columns, I want to select two of the columns (Month (string), Points(int)) throw them into a dictionary, and then binding that to my chart..

Here is my XAML::

```
<Window x:Class="Chart.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:DV="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
    xmlns:DVC="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <DVC:Chart Name="testchart" Title="Statistics" Width="500" Height="300" LegendTitle="Stats">
        <DVC:Chart.Series>
            <DVC:BarSeries Title="Points"
                           IndependentValueBinding=""
                           DependentValueBinding="">
            </DVC:BarSeries>
        </DVC:Chart.Series>
    </DVC:Chart>
</Grid>
```

And here is the code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;

namespace Chart
{

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Dictionary<string, int> _data = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        using (CE ctx = new CE())
        {
            var query = (from r in ctx.ChartOnes
                           select r).ToDictionary(k => k.Month);
        }


    }

}
}
```

Thanks Dessus for your timely response! I will play around with your suggestions today. I did get some help from a co-worker yesterday and he was able to show me how to get it to work. Here is the edited code snippets:

```
        <DVC:Chart Name="testchart" Title="Statistics" Width="500" Height="300" LegendTitle="Stats">
        <DVC:Chart.Series>
                <DVC:ColumnSeries Title="Points"
                           IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Key}"
                           DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Value.Points}">
                </DVC:ColumnSeries>
            </DVC:Chart.Series>
    </DVC:Chart>
```

and the code-behind:

```
        private void LoadBarChartData()
    {
        CE ctx = new CE();

        var query = (from r in ctx.ChartOnes
                     select new { Points = r.Points, Month = r.Month }).ToDictionary(k => k.Month);

        ((ColumnSeries)testchart.Series[0]).ItemsSource  = query;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look up a model view view-model (MVVM) example of how to do databinding in WPF for chart controls (see: http://geekswithblogs.net/BillSontag/archive/2009/10/31/wpf-2-way-data-binding.aspx). The way you are doing your query in code behind will make it annoying (but can work) to get a reference to your control, but MVVM will make life easier once you get it working and get used to it. Your Linq query appears like it should output to a datatable as opposed to a dictionary.

Side Note: Any updates to the underlying LINQ collections will not trigger updates in your chart control. For that you would need something like: http://bindablelinq.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks! The MVVM example was very simple and easy to understand.